# Ionic 2 - Setting value of a model driven form

Tags: angular, local-storage, ionic2, angular2-forms

I'm stuck with something related to a model driven form, built in Ionic 2, when I want to attribute previously saved values from a local storage to this form whenever I load this.

I managed to save it using the Storage service from Ionic, however I failed on attributing this saved data to the form. I get the following error:

> TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter

This is my code, so far:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-survey',
  templateUrl: 'survey.html',
  providers: [Storage]
})

export class Survey {
  form: FormGroup;
  networkStatus: boolean = true;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
              public formBuilder: FormBuilder, private storage: Storage) {

    // localstorage 
    this.storage = storage;

    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      "isPropertyOwner": ["", Validators.required],
      "familyMembers": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0)])],
      "ownsProperty": ["", Validators.required],
      "pragueIdentify": ["", Validators.required],
      "pesticidesUsage": ["", Validators.required],
      "propertyLevel": ["", Validators.required]
    });

    /* Check if form has been changed */
   this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => 
      this.storage.set('survey', data)
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // checking if there's something saved, then...
    if(this.storage.get('survey')) {
      this.storage.get('survey').then((data) => {
        console.log('This is ', data);
        this.form.value = data;
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form);
    this.storage.clear().then(() => {
      console.log('Keys have been cleared');
    });

  }
}
```

How could I attribute saved values to this form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FormGroup`'s property `value` is a read-only property which means you can't edit it directly. You need to use `get()` function to get each `FormControl` and then use `setValue()` function to change its value. Anyway, instead of this:

```
this.form.value = data;
```

You need to use this:

```
this.form.get('isPropertyOwner').setValue(data.isPropertyOwner);
this.form.get('familyMembers').setValue(data.familyMembers);
this.form.get('ownsProperty').setValue(data.ownsProperty);
this.form.get('pragueIdentify').setValue(data.pragueIdentify);
this.form.get('pesticidesUsage').setValue(data.pesticidesUsage);
this.form.get('propertyLevel').setValue(data.propertyLevel);
```

Comment: This worked as expected! Thank you very much, Хвала вам @StefanSvkota

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check after removing below two lines from your `constructor` as you have already declared `private storage: Storage` as `constructor` params.

```
// localstorage 
this.storage = storage;
```

Comment: Same error. I don't think this is the problem, as I'm not having problems to store or either retrieve stored values.  I can see through console that the value is correctly stored, however, I can't set it up.